# Implementing Concrete Model Classes for Abstract Models in Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-10

I'm currently developing a Laravel package where users can define their own models by implementing a certain abstract class. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to handle relationships between the abstract model and the concrete model, especially when the concrete class will be implemented later by the user.

Here's an example of what I have in mind:

```
abstract class ProductRules extends Model
{
    // Some common functionality
}

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Define a relationship with ProductRules.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function rules(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductRules::class);
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the ProductRules class is abstract and intended to be extended by users to define their own models. The Product class is where the relationship with ProductRules is defined.

However, since the concrete implementation of ProductRules will be done by the user and might not exist at the time of defining the relationship in Product, I'm encountering the error message: "Cannot instantiate abstract class App\ProductRule."